# How to output high quality Zoom webinar video after editing with Premiere Pro?

Tags: editing, video-quality

I used Adobe Premiere Pro in editing a Zoom webinar video, I noticed that after editing and exporting it, the resulting file size of the output file appeared blurry compared to the original. The file has been captured with the zoom screen recorded, video duration is about 1 hour 45 minutes. I did the edit using a Windows 10 OS.

Here are the properties of the input:
720x480 (1.2121), 29.97 fps. Lower, 48000Hz, Stereo

Here are the properties of the Output:
768x480, 29.97fps, Progressive VBR, 1 pass, Target 0.24 Mbpd. Max 0.24 Mbps AAC, 96 kbps, 48 kHz, Mono

How do I export my zoom webinar video out of Adobe Premiere Pro and still preserve the original quality?

My editing settings were: H.264 format with the Match Source preset. . Change the profile to High and the level to 5.2. I ticked Maximum Render Quality and also Render at Maximum Depth. Disable the aspect ratio link next to the dimensions and maintained the dimensions at 720 by 480 for 29.97 fps.

Here is a screenshot of the original footage:
[image]

And here is screenshot of the footage after edit and export:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your video is blurry is because of your target bitrate, which is 0.24 mbps. (I assume you meant mbps instead of mbpd). Raising this value to a target of 4 and a maximum of 6 should give you a significantly better result. It will also increase your filesize, however. I am assuming that the video might be between 200 and 300 MB.